# Switching appcompat & buildtools to v21, aapt.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to switch my project from API20 to API21.

When changing the gradle files to use AppCompat-v7 `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0` and `buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"` a windows error dialog popups saying `aapt.exe has stopped working`.

Comment: Might be related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629

Comment: It is related. You can currently run the v21 build tools or the v21 appcompat lib but running both causes the issue. Google is aware of it. No Eta for fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the latest build tools 21.1.1 and it will work

Comment: I was having this problem even for untouched new projects, and updating the build tools from 21.0.0 to 21.1.1 fixed it. Just mentioning it for anyone else who had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing build tools 21.1.1 solved the problem, here is the place where to change - gradle.build file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"//<--------------------!!!

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```